# Flutter how to turn Lists encoded as Strings for a SQFL database back to Lists concisely?

Tags: sql, flutter, dart, sqflite

I fear I'm trying to reinvent the wheel here.  I'm putting Objects into my SQFL database: 
https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite

some of the object fields are Lists of ints others are Lists of Strings.  I'm encoding these as plain Strings to place in a TEXT field in my SQFL database.

At some point I'm going to have to turn them back, I couldn't find anything on Google, which is surprising because this must be a very common occurrence with SQFL

I've started coding the 'decoding', but it's rookie dart.  Is there anything performant around I ought to use?

Code included to prove I'm not totally lazy, no need to look, edge cases make it fail.

```
  List<int> listOfInts = new List<int>();

  String testStringOfInts = "[1,2,4]";
  List<String> intermediateStep2 = testStringOfInts.split(',');

  int numListElements = intermediateStep2.length;

  print("intermediateStep2: $intermediateStep2, numListElements: $numListElements");
  for (int i = 0; i < numListElements; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
      listOfInts.add(int.parse(intermediateStep2[i].substring(1)));
      continue;
    }
    else if ((i) == (numListElements - 1)) {
      print('final element: ${intermediateStep2[i]}');
      listOfInts.add(int.parse(intermediateStep2[i].substring(0, intermediateStep2[i].length - 1)));
      continue;
    }
    else listOfInts.add(int.parse(intermediateStep2[i]));
  }
  print('Output: $listOfInts');

  /* DECODING LISTS OF STRINGS */
  String testString = "['element1','element2','element23']";
  List<String> intermediateStep = testString.split("'");
  List<String> output = new List<String>();

  for (int i = 0; i < intermediateStep.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      continue;
    } else {
      print('adding a value to output: ${intermediateStep[i]}');
      //print('value is a: ${(intermediateStep[i]).runtimeType}');
      output.add(intermediateStep[i]);
    }
  }
  print('Output: $output');
}
```

Comment: What is SQFL? The string example, is that always how the string are represented? What about integers? What happens if the string itself contains the `'` sign?

Comment: Hi @julemand101, I've added the link to the SQFL plugin database, f = 'Flutter'.  It's provides 4 datatypes: INTEGER, REAL, TEXT (Srings), BLOB.  So a fair number of my object fields are lists, either List<String> or List<int> they're converted to String then added to the Databse.  

But I wondered if there's a elegant, compact way to convert them back, from Strings to Lists.  It would help a lot.  Doubtless guard against mad edge cases I don't forsee & be more performant.

Comment: Do you know if any of the Strings in you arrays contains `,` or `'`?

Comment: This is a good conversation, yes, having done some research, I'm storing Google Firebase auto generated Ids in a few of the lists, and sadly both those punctuation  characters are permissible.  Man!  I'm going to have to encode the lists differently.  '/' Slash is an forbidden character in Firebase Ids, so I'm going to have to turn my List to a String then swap commas for slashes.  What a malarky!  Unless you know a better way?  Given this overhead of computetation I think for more abstract data types JSON data storage probably ends up with cleaner, maybe more robust code.

Comment: I don't say it is impossible to parse. Just that it makes it more difficult and I did not want to create a solution for something that is not going to be the case. But yes, you should differently use JSON encoding/decoding to store data as String's instead of inventing your own format. :)

Comment: After some thoughts, it is going to be too difficult to parse without any errors. If you can, you should change the storage format to JSON. (the problem is if a String contains e.g. Strings of the same format you are saving Strings like sub strings. You could say the format has a risk of string injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the integers your could make the parsing like:

```
void main() {
  print(parseStringAsIntList("[1,2,4]")); // [1, 2, 4]
}

List<int> parseStringAsIntList(String stringOfInts) => stringOfInts
    .substring(1, stringOfInts.length - 1)
    .split(',')
    .map(int.parse)
    .toList();
```

I need more information about how the Strings are saved in some corner cases like if they contain `,` and/or `'` since this will change how the parsing should be done. But if both characters are valid in the string (especially `,`) I will recommend you to change the storage format into JSON instead which makes it a lot easier to encode/decode and without the risk of using characters which can give you issues).

But a rather naive solution can be made like this if we know each String does not contain `,`:

```
void main() {
  print(parseStringAsStringList("['element1','element2','element23']"));
  // [element1, element2, element23]
}

List<String> parseStringAsStringList(String stringOfStrings) => stringOfStrings
    .substring(1, stringOfStrings.length - 1)
    .split(',')
    .map((string) => string.substring(1, string.length - 1))
    .toList();
```

Comment: Thankyou @julemand101, it's great to see a compact, clear way of doing things.  Love mapping in Dart. x Sam.